# How can I move mulitple windows at once to another monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I know there are many ways to move a single window to another monitor. What I would like is the ability to move multiple windows simultaneously to another monitor. For example, is there an application that can move all the windows from monitor 1 to monitor 2, maintaining relative positions? Or swap windows on one monitor with another?

Such a thing would be useful if you are working on several things at once, or want to shift your focus to a particular set of tasks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are programs out there that can move all open windows to one monitor simultaneously.  [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) is one that I know of.  However, unless you want **all** windows moved, you are going to have to go through them one at a time and select the ones you want moved anyway.

Using <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> will move each window to the next or previous monitor and retain its relative position.  You could move several windows over very quickly using this method, without having to move all of them.

Comment: This - I don't know of anything that'll move a SUBSET of windows, you either do them all at once or one at a time.

Comment: There are scripts for Display Fusion that let you move a subset of windows to another monitor. The scripts are easy to download with the built-in UI, and can be modified if needed. For example, I modified the "move all windows from monitor 2 to the current monitor" to instead: move all windows from the current monitor to the monitor I select in the popup. (I've since submitted this for inclusion in the downloadable script list)

Comment: Apart of "moving", if your second monitor is not going to be used you may want to set "Rearrange your display" to "Duplicate", this way apps are also showed all at once on the first monitor.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the accepted answer and @Venryx's on this very old but still relevant topic:

Using Display Fusion, download a Scripted Function called ["Move Visible Windows to Next Monitor"](https://www.displayfusion.com/ScriptedFunctions/View/?ID=d652ef8e-fd8d-47c4-a103-4c910958c48c) and assign a shortcut to it, I've used <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> since it's similar to other native window management shortcuts and is available. Save your settings and close the settings window.

Minimize all windows by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and open only the ones you want to move. Hit the shortcut you have assigned and voila.

Comment: Minimize all windows command is good. what about maximizing all windows command, is there one?

Answer (score 0):

Edge case: If you want to move all the windows to monitor A you can do the following without an additional program:

1. Make monitor A your main display (System -> Display -> dropdown: Multiple displays)
2. Win + P: Only monitor A
3. Open all windows by clicking on them (only Windows 11)
4. Win + P: Extend

note:

- Windows 11: *Remember window locations based on monitor connection* has to be disabled. (System -> Display -> dropdown: Multiple displays)
- Maybe there is a better way to activate all the windows (step 3). I tried Ctrl + Shift + M and *windows shake*, but none of them worked for me.
- This is probably only interesting if you regularly want to move all the windows to monitor A (because you have to change the *main display* otherwise)